# Wordpress chosen theme doesn't load

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have developed a wordpress theme and have uploaded and chosen that at http://www.digitalmanager.pk/ The problem is, when I am logged in my wordpress acccount on this sight, it shows the correct theme i.e. the one that I have chosen. But as soon as I logout of my wordpress account, it shows the default 2014 theme. Below is the screenshot, when I am logged in:
[image]
And the other one you can check for yourself by visiting the site at http://www.digitalmanager.pk/

**P.S.** I have removed the cache and tested but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be due to WP Super Cache Plugin. Just deactivate the WP Super Cache plugin from the Installed Plugins. Then upload upload your theme again.

Comment: In the Admin interface, under Settings->WP Super Cache, you can also just hit "Delete Cache" to clear things out when you make changes like this.